# How to get full payload from curl command in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl

The chunk of javascript below runs on an NodeJS box with the single goal of doing a curl request and output the returned payload.

The problem is, that if the returned payload from the request becomes to big, it will not output the complete payload.

What can I do to have the returned `stdout` 'wait' till it received the complete JSON payload?

Small JSON payload example returned by `stdout` (this is good):

```
{
    "Small data set": "Blablabla",
    ...etc...
    "End of data set": "Blablabla"
}
```

Big JSON payload example returned by `stdout` (this goes wrong):

```
{
    "Big data set": "Blablabla",
    ...etc...
    "End of
```

*Note: see the `<-- PROBLEM IS HERE` comments in the code.*

```
function curlReq(a, i, callback){
  curl_request = {
      "url": "URL",
      "headers": [
          "HEADERS"
      ],
      "data": {
          "DATA"
    }
  };

  /**
   * Merge together in curl request (curl -i -H --data [url])
   */
  curl_render = 'curl -H "'+curl_request.headers[0]+'" '+
      ' -H "'+curl_request.headers[1]+'" '+
      ' -H "'+curl_request.headers[2]+'" '+
      " --data '"+JSON.stringify(curl_request.data)+"' "+
      curl_request.url;

  exec(curl_render, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      callback(stdout); // <-- PROBEM IS HERE
  });
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    /**
     * GET a = action
     * GET v = value
     */
    q = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
    if(q.a && q.i){
      curlReq(q.a, q.i, function(stdout){
         res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
         res.end(stdout); // <-- PROBEM IS ALSO HERE
      });
    } else {
      /**
       * Nothing found to process so end it.
       */
      res.end('No action available');
    }
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Any errors in console?

Comment: Why are you using `child_process.exec` to execute cURL when there is good built-in http support *and* there are many npm modules that extend this support (e.g. `request`)?

Comment: @mscdex you are absolutly right, I needed this for a temp solution based on an available cli command. I was curious to know why this goes wrong though